# cannot print what i read from file python

Tags: python, python-3.x, readlines

Ok. so I wrote a program that reads each line from a reader object.

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Jayesh B\Documents\Programming\Python\Practicals\Program5\program5.txt','r') as target:
    lines = target.readlines()
    newfllines = []
    for line in lines:
        if line[0].lower() == 'a':
            newfllines.append(line)
    print(lines)
    a = target.read()
    print(a)
```

My file is not empty as printing lines gives me the output

```
['aaditya\n', 'aaaaaaab\n', 'efsgrbdb\n', 'grr\n', 'gegeb\n', 'ee\n', 'adi \n', 'test123\n', 'sb\n', 'fsbr\n', 'bfs\n', 'brsbwb\n', 'wb\n', 'wbwb\n', 'wbe']
```

but the second print statement does not give any output. Can anyone tell what i am doing wrong?
Please note.. I am using the python version : 3.8.6

```
Python 3.8.6 (tags/v3.8.6:db45529, Sep 23 2020, 15:52:53) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Comment: You should add `target.seek(0)` before the second `read` call. This is to change the file object’s position. becuase after the first `readlines` call the file position will be at the end of the file.

Comment: After `target.readlines()`, you had been reached end of file, so next read get nothing.

Comment: ok thanks it worked i had to seek it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have reached end of the stream, you need to re-read the file again (you don't need to close the file as you are using `with`) and also fix bad indentation:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Jayesh B\Documents\Programming\Python\Practicals\Program5\program5.txt','r') as target:
  lines = target.readlines()
  newfllines = []
  for line in lines:
    if line[0].lower() == 'a':
      newfllines.append(line)
print(lines)
a = open(r'C:\Users\Jayesh B\Documents\Programming\Python\Practicals\Program5\program5.txt','r').read()
print(a)
```

Also you can go to the top again using `target.seek(0)`

Comment: i fixed indentation still it wont work. but as you suggested to open file again it worked. now closing the question thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `target.readlines()` method, the pointer goes through the entire file and is at the end, so when you call the `taeget.read()` method, there is nothing to read as the pointer is at the end of the file. You can fix this by using the `target.seek(0)` method after `target.readlines()` as it will reset your pointer and bring it to the first character in the file. Also, make sure that the indentation is correct, everything should be in the `with` code-block, as the file is closed as soon as you unindent out of that code-block.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(r'program.txt','r') as target:
    lines = target.readlines()
    newfllines = []
    for line in lines:
        if line[0].lower() == 'a':
            newfllines.append(line)
    print(lines)
    target.seek(0)
    a = target.read()
    print(a)
    print(newfllines)
```

output

```
['ciao\n', 'come\n', 'stai\n', 'a\n', 'a\n', 'a']
ciao
come
stai
a
a
a
['a\n', 'a\n', 'a']
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to read a closed file. Instead you can try this.

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Jayesh B\Documents\Programming\Python\Practicals\Program5\program5.txt','r') as target:
        lines = target.readlines()
newfllines = []
for line in lines:
    if line[0].lower() == 'a':
        newfllines.append(line)
print(lines)
with open(r'C:\Users\Jayesh B\Documents\Programming\Python\Practicals\Program5\program5.txt','r') as target:
    a = target.read()
print(a)
```